# How do you do the equivalent of a "git show tagname" with JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I can't find anything in org.eclipse.jgit.api that looks even remotely plausible. I was under the impression that "git show" is a porcelain command, and I see plenty of other classes for much more obscure commands.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The RevTag class represents a tag in JGit. To read a tag from a repository you'd want to use a RevWalk like so:

```
Repository repository = ...
ObjectId objectId = ObjectId.fromString("a33a2d4dff046b3a19e36b3d1026fbcc5b806889");
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
  RevTag revTag = revWalk.parseTag(objectId);
  // do something with revTag
}
```

The JGit project also offers a command line interpreter with functionality much like native git. It can be found in the org.eclipse.jgit.pgm bundle/library. I recommend to have a look into the [show command](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/src/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/Show.java) if you want to learn more about obtaining information from a tag or the referenced commit.

Comment: My code throws ``org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object 3dfc94dd89b1bd2d30f738d63fd213820ea1a496 is not a tag.``